# Trying to understand an inline function

Tags: c, inline-functions

I am studying the following function:

```
inline xint dtally(xint x)
{
    xint t = 0;
    while (x) t += 1 << ((x % 10) * 6), x /= 10;
    return t;
}
```

I just want to know what makes this feature i.e. which computes and stored in the variable `t`.

Comment: What do you mean by "what makes this feature"?

Comment: @Deduplicator - yup, just went and checked. Comment rescinded.

Comment: what is xint?  If we knew that detail, then we could answer your question.

Comment: That comma operator makes me cry. I hope you didn't find this in production code. If so, please tell us, so we can avoid that guy.

Comment: This function is probably bugged (unless you are on ILP64 system), change `1` to `(xint)1`

Answer (score 2):

This counts the number of base 10 digits in the number `x` in `t`, separated by 6-width bit fields.

Note that each shift length is a multiple of 6. So if a digit is 0 the shift is 0, if the digit is 1 the shift is 6, if the digit is 9 the shift is 54, and so forth.

The reason 6 is used I think is so it fits under 64 bits.

Comment: The count of each possible base 10 digit in x, i.e., each 6-bit wide field in the output should hold the count of the digits corresponding to that offset in x. Bits 0-5 holds the number of 0's, bits 6-11 the number of 1's, 12-17 the number of 2's, etc.